# That's very nice of you

Tags: phrase-usage

> 1. It's very nice of you to help me.
> 2. That's very nice of you to help me.

I know the first sentence is correct. But how about the second sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second doesn't quite work. Either of these is good:

> It's very nice of you to help me.
>
> That's very nice of you.

*That* in the second sentence refers to "(you) helping me" - so it's redundant to include "to help me".

*It* in the first sentence is a [dummy pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun) - it does not refer to any agent. So it's ok to be explicit about the thing that's very nice of you to do in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence is at best awkward.  One might well say just:

> That's very nice of you.

leaving what was nice to the context, the previous discussion or action.